# Accessing Azure SQL Database from Access (without port 1433)

Tags: sql, ms-access, azure, firewall, ms-access-2013

So I'm building a pretty simple application in Access 2013, and our company recommended using Azure SQL Database for the backend (due to the cost and simplicity of setting up/maintenance). However, their recommendation left us with a massive problem. Port 1433 is blocked on our company's network, and it's such a big company, I can't get it unblocked.

I don't know too much about having a middle-tier, but what are my options here? Is there a simple way to connect to the database without accessing this port?

Thanks

Comment: is your server on-premise?

Comment: Which server? The back-end for this application will be in Azure only. Servers for internal LAN are on-premise, but global company-wide policies dictate that port 1433 cannot be opened.

Comment: Not sure why your company group policy blocks SQL port 1433. you have two option, either unblock the port or find another db server and host it locally OR ask your azure hosting if they can change the port

Comment: Apparently it's because of the SQL Slammer worm. Seriously annoying as they recommended this service in the first place, and obviously didn't think we'd want a direct connection

Comment: re: Slammer - That was almost 12 years ago. Your IT people sure do hold a grudge.

Comment: I hadn't even heard of it (it was before my time). The problem also is that this will be accessed in a few locations globally (but only by a small number of people) so each network may have it blocked

Comment: use MySQL its free :)

Comment: I wish I could, but it's a choice between AWS and Azure. Again, company policy unfortunately.

Comment: They do understand that you only need port 1433 *outbound* (not inbound), do they?

Comment: I'll shout at them some more.

Comment: No one in their right mind would open port 1433 for INCOMING. I did this 10 years ago, and in less then 15 minutes the SQL server logs showed “bots” attempting to logon as “sa” etc.  So no kidding, port 1433 cannot be opened up for incoming. However, allowing client computer to initiate a connection to Skype, Lync etc. or sql server should be fine. No one is asking for incoming 1433 – that is and would be a disaster. However, allowing outgoing client computers to use port 1433 is a different matter. And what port are they suggesting they open up for outgoing?

Comment: Yeah exactly. The issue here is only around 1433, no other port. This is because Azure SQL Databases are fixed at port 1433. I'm trying to reason with the IT guys.

Answer (score 1):

You could fire up a Azure VM with SQL Server already installed.  Then you should be able to change the ports to your liking.

Check out this post...

http://roberteichenseer.wordpress.com/2012/07/06/nderung-default-port-sql-server-innerhalb-einer-azure-vm/

Comment: That's true, but the problem is that it's only a small application or a handful of users. The price/maintenance of a VM just isn't feasible given the scale.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to open up 1433 outbound in your works firewall not the 1433 inbound.

Most security teams are ok to open the outbound port. Opening the outbound will give you the access to connect and access the data inside Azure.